# How to open multiple tabs from href list?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, href

So I have got all my target href links but I don't know how to open multiple tabs from that href list where each tab should have the same code running.

```
driver.get('my website')

elem_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-watch"]/div[5]/div/span')
eps = elem_list.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for ep in eps:
    episode = ep.get_attribute('href')
    #print(episode)
```

Comment: Take care, when you open new tab you will have to focus on that tab in driver. Im pretty sure there is something to do this better, you can try to do ctrl+click on each ep item

Comment: @Wonka so how can i make it open one by one and run the code and repeat

Comment: You can search on google before ask